# Extrair número de telefone com API em Python pandas

Tags: python, api, pandas

Tenho uma API que extrai o numero de telefone. Ela funciona da seguinte forma. Ao passar um numero nela, me retorna 3 variaveis do tipo string contendo telefone com codigo do pais, tipo se é celular ou fixo e o

```
telefone,tipo,ddd = extract(numero=34900001111).get_numero()
```

Só que preciso pegar todos os números de uma coluna em um dataframe e criar 3 outras colunas com as strings retornadas para cada número dessa coluna. Então tentei fazer uma função para usar a API da seguinte forma:

```
def telefone():
for i in df2['TELEFONE']:
    telefone,tipo,ddd = extract(numero=i).get_numero()
    df2['TEL'] = telefone
    df2['TIPO'] = tipo
    df2['DDD'] = ddd
```

Dessa forma que eu fiz ela esta pegando um número e criando as 3 colunas, mas sempre com a mesma saída para todas linhas. Alguém pode me ajudar a descobrir onde estou errando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geralmente é possível fazer operações no Pandas sem utilizar o comando *for*, fazendo uso de algo chamado de "vetorização".

Veja se isto funciona:

```
import numpy as np

# separando a extração de cada variável

@np.vectorize
def telefone(num):

    return extract(numero=num).get_numero()[0]

@np.vectorize
def tipo(num):

    return extract(numero=num).get_numero()[1] 

@np.vectorize
def ddd(num):

    return extract(numero=num).get_numero()[2]



# criando as colunas novas


df2['TEL']  = telefone(df2['TELEFONE'])

df2['TIPO'] = tipo(df2['TELEFONE'])

df2['DDD']  = ddd(df2['TELEFONE'])
```

Comment: Depois quero olhar melhor pra entender como essa vetorização do `numpy`. Mas pode ter certeza que funcionou. Obrigado

Comment: E no caso seu eu tiver 2 parâmetros , como ficara? Tipos precisasse passar o Telefone e DDD, para criar as mesmas colunas?